# how to handle the xmlparsing

Tags: iphone

Iam developing one applcation.In that,in my xml file having the threetags with same name with different data.So how to differentiate that data.please inform me how to handle this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the sequence of tags coming then u can declare an int as a counter variable in following method.

```
-(void)  parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser didStartElement:(NSString *) elementName    namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict
```

For eg: when first time tag is visited set cnt = 1, second time cnt = 2, and third time cnt = 3.
Then using the value of counter save the data to 3 different NSMutableArray in the following method:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I dont Know the sequence of tags.one name is for my name,another is for mother name and other one is for father name.How to differentiate the data.

Comment: Then u can ask your web service guy to give you the data in particular sequence or make 3 different tags coz you won't be able to put any login if there's no pattern in data. For eg. If first time u get name in "First Father Mother" and then next time if it comes as "Mother Father First" you'll never be able to manage it.